# How to populate a dropdown list with a custom field in odoo12?

Tags: odoo-view, odoo-12

Generally when a many2one field is declared and a model is referred to in that many2one field, this drop down list populates the entries from the field named name but i want to populate the drop down list with a custom field say companyName. How can i achieve this? An example would be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know that we can achieve this using

Method 1 works only if there is no field named "name" and if there is already a field named "name" then try method 2

1. Using the **_rec_name** = '[field-name]'.  for eg. `_rec_name = 'companyName'`
2. By overriding the **name_get()** method in the source model i.e., in the model from which you want the fields to populate the list with.